# Regex: How to match instances of text, including spaces and new lines?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want a regular expression which will match one or more instances of text followed by a newline. Following the final match of text followed by a newline I would like for a single further newline, then no more. How would I go about achieving this?

I am having difficulty in enforcing the one new line rule.

My (wrong) attempts include:
`[^\n]+\n\n`
`([^\n]+\n[^\n]+)*\n\n`

An example of text i would like to match is:

`"Hello text\nMore text\nLast one\n\n"`

With a non-match on both:

`"Hello text\nMore text\nLast one\n\n\n"`

`"Hello text\nMore text\nLast one\n"`

PLease help me. thanks

Comment: Please post your own attempts

Comment: Please go read [ask]. The question title is far from good as well.

Comment: i am sorry @CBroe i will read and do this next time. Lance Toth see my attempts above

Comment: Your question and your example do not match. You want the regex to match _some text including spaces, a new line_, and also 2 lines, right? So 4 full lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking to match any number of lines of text, followed by only 1 additional newline at the end, simply: `^(.+\n)+\n(?!\n)` will do what you'd like.

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/Hy3buP/1

Explanation:

```
^                        - Assert position at start of string
 (.+\n)+                 - Match any positive number of lines of text ending in newline
        \n               - Match the next newline
          (?!\n)         - Do a negative lookahead to ascertain there are no more newlines.
```

Comment: No, i want to match stuff mainly like "Hello text\nMore text\nLast one\n\n"

Comment: Ok, so only a single extra newline at the end?

Comment: I need to enforce only one newline per line (except the end where there need to be two consecutive ones)